# Synchronized method multy threading app

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I trying to use Synchronized methods, but I faced some interesting behavior such as:

I have three threads **ThreadA** - that invokes Increment method, **ThreadB** that invokes Decrement method and **ThreadC**  that print current value;
But some values look incorrect:

debug:
Preparing threads
false
**1**
0
0
0
0
0
**1**
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0....

when it's supposed to have all 0 and 1 or other values;

My code is below:

```
package concurrency;

public class Synchronization {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Preparing threads");

    Counter cnt = new Counter();

    Thread threadA = new Thread(new ThreadA(cnt));

    Thread threadB = new Thread(new ThreadB(cnt));

    Thread ThreadC = new Thread (new ThreadC(cnt));


    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
    ThreadC.start();
}

private static class ThreadA implements Runnable {

    private final Counter counter;

    public ThreadA(Counter cnt) {

        counter = cnt;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("ThreadA");
        System.out.println(((Boolean) 
        Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()).toString());
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                counter.Increment();
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException ThreadA");
        }
        System.out.println("ThreadA finished");

    }
}

private static class ThreadB implements Runnable {

    private final Counter counter;

    public ThreadB(Counter cnt) {

        counter = cnt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("ThreadB");

        try {
            while (true) {

                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    break;
                }
                counter.Decrement();

                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedExcepion threadB");

        }
        System.out.println("ThreadB Finished");

    }
}

private static class ThreadC implements Runnable {

    private final Counter counter;

    public ThreadC(Counter cnt) {

        counter = cnt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("ThreadC");

        try {
            while (true) {

                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(counter.getValue());

                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedExcepion threadB");

        }
        System.out.println("ThreadB Finished");

    }
}

private static class Counter {

    private int value = 0;

    public synchronized void Increment() {
        value++;
    }

    public synchronized void Decrement() {
        value--;
    }

    public synchronized int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your question is a request to debug your code; you don't ask anything specific, you don't give us details of how it works, just an indication of expected output being all 0s or all 1s or something. We don't normally just jump onto someone else's code to debug, maybe especially not multithreaded code. What we do is answer more specific questions about something you don't understand. Use a debugger and/or trace statements to frame a more specific question, and you're more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: It looks like you got your explanation :)

Comment: Okay, thanks you're right. I should have to debug it by myself; But from our community I was expecting not to debug my code but to check and advice is my logic correct.

Comment: But that's precisely not how this site works. You first must find your problem and use that information to ask a specific question.

Comment: I found and shared my problem, I described it well and for those it might be interesting I published my code, so what wrong with my question? I didn't ask nobody to debug my code. If you're considering my question as stupid - okay ignore or criticise it constructively, this is how this site works.

Comment: @MSD - By posting your code without asking any explicit question, you **implicitly** asked people to debug your code.  This is basic English communication.  What did you expect from  your "sharing" your problem?  Sympathy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you see here that is unexpected. This code has 3 threads using a common shared counter. There is sufficient synchronization to make sure threads don't modify the shared data in an invalid way or see stale values. But the output will vary depending on which threads get more CPU time when. There is no requirement that these threads run in any particular order, what threads run and who gets the lock may seem arbitrary. The output from this is going to be unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you, for human and kind style of answer.  I will try to get more deeply into the synchronization and concurrency, and maybe found something interesting regarding the issue; Thank you again.